# Print Filenames and Sorted Data

Tags: bash

I have a script that sorts files within a directory based on the number of appearances of a certain word found within the files. I want to display the sorted list with the name of the file in front. I can search through the files with a loop to sort and display them, and separately I can trim path names to just get the file name, but I'm not sure how to have the output as the filename then the number I'm sorting by. I can get the formatting right with awk, in that I can print a string in front of the number, just not sure about getting the file name.

What I have now is:

```
path="/home/Downloads/folder/*"
trim_path=$(echo a | sed -r "s/.+\/(.+)\../\1/")

(for f in $a
do
    tr -s ' ' '\n' < $f | grep -c 'Word'
done
) | sort -g | awk '{print $b, $1}'
```

The output is

```
300 300
302 302
304 304
... ...
```

I think my trim_path variable is probably going about it the wrong way, and I imagine I'm instead meant to somehow pull the path from sorted data, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `echo a` will simply output the string `a`. Did you mean `echo "$path"`?

Comment: Also, what do you hope `$b` will result in in Awk? If `b` is not a valid Awk variable, it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `tr/grep` is the best way to count words in the file... 
Answering your question.
you can use `basename` command to get file name only. No need for that trim_path variable. You can use sort `-k` parameter to sort on the second command. so no need to use awk. So it could be something like this:

```
path="/home/Downloads/folder/*"
for i in $path; do 
    echo `basename $i` `tr -s ' ' '\n' < $i | grep -c 'Word'`; 
done |sort -g -k 2
```